# I'm trying to use jquery bind instead of live but my function only seems to trigger once

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery "inView" plugin to detect whether an element is in the viewport, when it is it triggers an ajax request to load more elements.

My current function looks like this:

```
  function nth_view(){
    var elem = $('#sglsPosts .sglsPostContainer:last-child');
    elem.addClass('nthCunt');
    }nth_view();

function sidebarScroll() {
    var offset = 0;
    $('.nthCunt').live('inview', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('nthCunt')) {
            $this.removeClass('nthCunt');
            var singlePost = $('#sglsPosts');
            var ajax_url = singlePost.attr('data-url');
            var cat = singlePost.attr('data-cat');
            var loadDiv = $(".loadDiv");
            offset = parseInt(offset) + 10;
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "HTML",
                url: ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'side_scroll',
                    offset: offset,
                    cat: cat
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    /*loadDiv.show(); //show image loading*/
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#sglsPosts nav').append(data);
                    nth_view();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
sidebarScroll();
```

I need to upgrade my jQuery but when I do `live` becomes an unrecognised method so I need to use `bind`, but when I do my function only seems to fire once.

Why is it only functioning once, and how can I use the `bind` function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest fashion in jQuery is to use the `on` method, which has overloads to replace `bind`, `live` and `delegate` methods.

The equivalent of your code would be to bind a delegate to the body element:

```
$(document.body).on('inview', '.nthCunt', function () {
```

However, if possible you should bind it to an element closer to the element where the event will occur, so that the code doesn't have to check the selector for every such event that happens in the page.

Comment: Aha! Nice, worked great. I'll tick it correct once SO lets me. I'll find something else to bind it to in a bit, but this works so thanks.